# How do you call a function once a day at a certain time in c++?

Tags: c++, timer

Well i need to figure out how to call a function at a certain time if my application is running.

it will probably be in a while loop and check the time but i don't want it to check the time every minute but i don't want it to miss the exact time, say 18:00.

is there any way do to this?

Comment: Depends on the platform.

Comment: Do you really need to do this in code, or would your purposes be equally served by a scheduler like Windows' Scheduled Tasks or Cron in Unix? If you do need it in code, what platform are you using?

Comment: yes i do need it to be in code. platform would be win nt and above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I don't know why I assumed this was Windows.  I don't see anywhere that it says so.  The API info below is only applicable for Windows but the principle is the same.  Boost.Asio has portable async timers, if not Windows.

**Windows Info :** When your app starts up, check the interval remaining to your desired event and start a [Timer Queue Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to pop at the appropriate time.  The timer will pop after an initial interval, and then repeatedly after a periodic interval.

> **CreateTimerQueueTimer Function**
>
> Creates a timer-queue timer. This
>   timer expires at the specified due
>   time, then after every specified
>   period. When the timer expires, the
>   callback function is called.

Much more efficient to make this event-driven than to periodically check the clock.

Comment: hey Steve so this will actually make a thread without using boost?

Comment: If you are on Windows and use this, the required threading will be handled behind the scenes - in short, yes.

Comment: If you want more portable way to do it, the Qt library has QTimer. But it may be an overkill to use such a large library just for that.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to call a specific function from within a program that's already running, use Boost's [Date Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library and [Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace gregorian = boost::gregorian;
namespace posix_time = boost::posix_time;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

asio::io_service io_service_;
asio::deadline_timer timer_ (io_service_);
```

Then set the time. This is an example using a string of the desired time, like "18:00:00". (Note that Boost defaults to UTC for the timestamps!)

```
gregorian::date today = gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
posix_time::time_duration usertime = posix_time::duration_from_string(time)
posix_time::ptime expirationtime (today, usertime);
```

Now set the timer to call `foo()`:

```
timer_.expires_at (expirationtime);
timer_.async_wait (foo);    // use Boost::bind() if you want a member function
```

You can add as many timers as you want to `timer_` by using the above two code snippets. When everything is ready:

```
io_service_.run ();
```

Note that this will take over the current thread. So you must call `run()` from a different thread if you want the rest of your program to keep going. (Obviously, use Boost's [Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) library for that.)

Comment: Hey chris thanks for posting this. this is very useful if using boost. I needed a way without using boost because i needed my app to be only one exe and i didn't want to statically link boost. I should have stated this in my initial question, truly sorry about the misguiding. i hope someone sees your answer and use it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the operating system tools that provide this and you only worry about writing your function.  But if thats not an option you will need to just check the clock periodicly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a scheduled task in your system that will notify your application.
If your system is Linux you can use cron for example.